# Gulp - the best way of minifying multiple css files into one?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, gulp, gulp-concat, gulp-clean-css

What is the best way of minify multiple css files into one?

The gulp task below causing two issues after the minification and concatenation:

1. bootstraps glyphicons that I use have disappeared.
2. some of my styles are broken. The task seems to have **re-arranged** the position of some styles, for instance `.footer{...}` was placed below `html{...}` but it is now above `html{...}`. How can i stop it from rearranging them?

gulpfile:

```
gulp.task('minify-css', function() {
    return gulp.src([
        'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
        'vendor/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css',
        'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css',
        'node_modules/jasny-bootstrap/dist/css/jasny-bootstrap.css',
        'css/style.css',
        ])
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(cleanCSS({debug: true}))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(concat('bundle.min.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it help you but I think you could use SASS preprocessing by gulp-sass. There you could import all of your dependencies and let gulp-sass to minify the result. I have similar approach in my gulp devstack. SASS (libsass) can import *.css files, e.g. in your main.scss you can write

```
@import "path/to/file";
```

Note that without .css extension!
If you not familiar with SASS I recommend to give it a chance.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a common solution but sometimes it helps. I make two min. bundles: 'head.bundle.min.css' and 'foot.bundle.min.css' just like you did. In head.bundle.min.css I collect styles which must be first. And finally I concatenated two min bundles in one.